# DispForm.aspx errors and will not load

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Howdy, I'm in WSS3. I am using a list with a custom DispForm which includes DVWP from other lists rolled into this one. It has been working for quite some time, and today I hopped in to change the sort order using SharePoint Designer and SPD errored stating it couldn't read the file. So I opened it as text and I had about 500K lines, most blank. I fought that for a while and finally rolled back to a previous version of the page that I had backed up.

Now my backup is erroring on the ListFormWebPart that should be showing my item. I'm not using a custom form web part. I can fix it by switching the FormType to 8. From what I read online, 8 is for NewForm, DispForm should have 4. Welp, the page loads using 8.

My issue now is that my list views won't link to the dispform. the title field URL shows http://site/?ID=123. Back in SPD, and the properties of the list looking at supporting files, the display form was missing. So I set it to dispform.aspx and it didn't stick. I played around with switching around the content type setting by enabling content types, then pick the content type from the supporting files dialog then set the dispform. This appears to keep the setting in the list properties but the web site still doesn't link to my form. If I specify EditForm.aspx as my display form, it works and opens the editform.

I tried clearing the entire page, and then using SPD inserting a list form for the this list. It immediately errored because the formtype was 4. I changed it to 8, and the page loads when I type the URL in directly, but it's the new form, it's not the display form.

I loaded SharePoint Manager 2007 on the server and reviewed the list and content types. The display form was specified as I noted, but for the content type the edit form was blank. On the list the edit form wasn't blank.

So now i'm done crying under my desk, and about to head home so I thought I'd float this out there. My guess is my list or the content type has a corrupted display definition or schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a fix on http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2000861